# js / jquery object display just a quick flash

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

I am messing around with js objects today, ran across a weird glitch.

```
<form method="get" action="" name="start" >

<fieldset>

<label for="date">Date</label>

<input type="date" name="date" id="date" />

<div>&nbsp;</div>

<label for="smiles">Starting Mileage</label>

<input type="number" name="smiles" id="smiles" />

<div>&nbsp;</div>

<label for="stime">Starting Time</label>

<input type="time" name="stime" id="stime" />

<div>&nbsp;</div>

<label for="submit">Click To Save</label>

<input type="submit"  name="submit" id="submit" />

</fieldset>

</form>

<div id="display" name="display" ></div>


`<script>src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js">`

</script>

<script>

$(document).ready(function() {

$("#submit").click(function(){

var date =   document.getElementById("date").value;

 var smiles = document.getElementById("smiles").value;

 var stime =  document.getElementById("stime").value; 



 var record =  { date2: date, smiles2: smiles, stime2: stime };

document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = smiles;

 });

});

</script>
```

when you run this, the record.smiles flashes in the div id='display' but doesn't stay.  Why?  This is asking for more details, I don't know how much more in detail I can go, hopefully this will be enough verbage to make it happen.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It flashes and then disappears because you are clicking a submit button and the default action of a button on a form is to try and submit the form.

To prevent the default action you just need to add a single line of code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#submit").click(function(){

     event.preventDefault(); // <----add this

     var date =   document.getElementById("date").value;

     var smiles = document.getElementById("smiles").value;

     var stime =  document.getElementById("stime").value; 



     var record =  { date2: date, smiles2: smiles, stime2: stime };

     document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = smiles;

 });

});
```

Also, you mentioned you are "playing around with javascript objects" so i just wanted to let you know that the code you have written here:

```
 var record =  { date2: date, smiles2: smiles, stime2: stime };
```

Could be completely removed and not affect the behavior of your program at all.

It is also unnecessary to add the "2" to your key name. They can just be the same as your variable if you want. Also, as a matter of style and readability formatting you object literals like this is slightly more readable if they become more complex. Have fun!

```
var record =  { 
    date: date, 
    smiles: smiles, 
    stime: stime 
};
```

Comment: thank you both, that indeed was the answer.  I did have my object setup as in your second example, I straightened it out to make it easier to post here.  I also added the 2 to the key name to troubleshoot the script.  Again, thank you both.

Answer (score 1):

You must prevent the default action of the submit button, otherwise it will submit the form at the same time, therefore reloading the page, try adding:

```
$("#submit").click(function(event) {

    event.preventDefault()
```